# How do I make an include for an existing list in C #?

Tags: c#

I have in the database a table of "Afaza" in which there is a "groupId" data
If I were searching in linq I could display the groups by code-

```
         return await _context.Afaza.Where (x => ....). Include (c => c.Group) .OrderByDescending (e => e.Date) .Cast <Afaza> () .ToListAsync ();
```

But I have to do a search that cannot be done in linq so I kept it in line

```
         List <Afaza> returnList = new List <Afaza> ();
```

But if I do to him

```
         return await returnList.Include (c => c.Group) .OrderByDescending (e => e.Date) .Cast <Afaza> () .ToListAsync ();
```

There is an error message
'IList ' does not contain a definition for 'Include' and no accessible extension method 'Include' accepting a first argument of type 'IList ' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference? )

How can I include to an existing list?

Comment: `Include()` tells the database to load and include additional data. If you simply create a `List()` there is no connection to the database and so it's impossible to load additional data from db. It would help if you would add some more details.

Comment: rerturnList will be empty so an include can do nothing here? As returnList has no conection to the database it is just a list it couldn't get the info needed here anyway. If you want to have Group do it while you have the context before transfering data into a List<T>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends.

If you don't have too much data you can select (and filter as much as possible) as in your first example and filter a second time in code.

```
// select all from DB
_context.Afaza.Include(c => c.Group).ToList();
<filter here in code>
```

Otherwise you can do explicit loading for every item.

```
_context.Entry(yourSingleListEntry).Reference(x => x.Group).Load();
```

But I wonder how you want to get these items with "But I have to do a search that cannot be done in linq"

Comment: First of all thank you very much, but regarding the "wonder".
You do not have to wonder, I have a search process for a bargain that should include a number of things that can not be done in linq